# jqplot filltozero one element from series

Tags: jquery, jqplot

jqplot has an option "fillToZero"

```
seriesDefaults:{ rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}},
```

the problem is when the series just like the picture has the blue series that starts from 400+
all the important and  interesting data which is the "Develop" and "System Testing" is almost unseen.

Any way to "fillToZero" the "Done" so that the series will start from 400?

[image]

i tried:

```
series: [{label: 'Done', fillToZero: true}]
```

but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the `fillToZero` option, the y axis scale is controlled by the `min` property, so you can set this to a higher value to leave more room to show the part of the data that's actually changing:

```
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        fill: true,
        fillToZero: true
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            // hardcoded in this example but in real code you would calculate
            // an appropriate value e.g. with underscore/lodash
            min: 400 
        }
    }
```

See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tNLZJ/4/

Comment: You are setting the min hardcoded, the fillToZero is auto calculating the minimum.

Comment: @AceOfSpades perhaps you can explain more about how your graph should look. I thought I understood you wanted it to start at 400.

Comment: the chart's values are not static and the min is not always 400. the chart changes all the time, that was an example image.

Comment: perhaps a mocked-up example image of what you expect it to look like would clear up the confusion

Comment: same as you'r solution in jsfiddle, just dynamic and not fixed to 400.

Comment: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.fillToValue

maybe? and pass in some sensible values